# Comparion of values won't work without delay

Tags: c, embedded

I'm writing an application that will time mouse latency for our product.

The way it works is that it sends a mouse movement, and measures the time between then and when we get a pixel change on screen.

Why does this delay affect the program.

```
int check_for_pixel_change() {

    // Gets the pixels R value
    unsigned char value = *((unsigned char *) (0x100));

    // If this delay is not here then the loop will always return 1
    usleep(5);

    if(value == (0x80)) return 0;
    else return 1;
}

int main() {
    // Send move / start timer

    while(check_for_pixel_change());

    // stop timer
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note: You can simplify the **entire** code to `while (*(unsigned char*)0x100 != 0x80);`. Assuming that you have some sort of scheduler (OS) in the background, perhaps that `usleep` allows some other thread to complete its work and set `0x80` at that address. If it's an ISR (and not a thread), then there has to be some other reason, because an ISR is always at a higher priority than any other thread in your system.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think of that, I have now changed my code to `*(volatile unsigned char*)` and that seems to do the trick.

Comment: Change `unsigned char value` to `volatile unsigned char value` and then check.

Comment: The fact that `volatile` has solved the problem implies that the problem was the result of a compiler optimization (hence my speculation of a concurrency (multi-threading) issue was wrong).

Comment: You should read and _understand_ about `volatile` and not just use it if someone tells you to! (although he is actually right). It is also good practive to have global variables not at function scope, so it is clearly visible as such.

Comment: Someone post an answer - this is not what comments are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that worked.

Thanks to @barak-manos && @santosh-a.

I needed to change the char to volatile because it would be constantly changing by a different program.

```
int check_for_pixel_change() {

    // Gets the pixels R value
    volatile unsigned char value = *(volatile unsigned char *) (0x100);

    if(value == (0x80)) return 0;
    else return 1;
}

int main() {
    // Send move / start timer

    while(check_for_pixel_change());

    // stop timer
    return 0;
}
```